# how to wrap renderItem function of flat list with useMemo

Tags: reactjs, react-usememo

there is simple renderItem function, all I need is wrap it with 'useMemo',
but encounter an error as seem below;
[image]

original:

```
  const renderItem = ({ item, index }: { item: any; index: number }) => {
        return (
          <QuizRow
            startTutorial={startTutorial}
            backgroundColor={item.pack_color}
            isReinforcement={item.isAdaptive && adaptive?.has_quiz}
            quiz={item}
            imgSource={item.topic_image}
            due={item.due_date}
            style={{ marginBottom: 12 }}
            onPress={() => pressQuiz(item, index)}
          />
        )
      }

...
return (

         <FlatList
            extraData={assignedQuizzes || adaptive}
            data={quizList}
            keyExtractor={item => item.quiz_id}
            renderItem={renderItem}
          />
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `useMemo` ? `renderItem` is a function, If you want to memoïze this function, you should use `useCallback`

Comment: I dont want it to re-render for same item

Answer (score 0):

You should use a second arrow function as your main JSX/TSX function.
It's right to use `useCallback` as well. At the end of the day, you're returning a React component so useMemo could fit too.

```
 const renderItem = useMemo(()=> {
    return ({ item, index }: { item: any; index: number }) => (
     <QuizRow
        startTutorial={startTutorial}
        backgroundColor={item.pack_color}
        isReinforcement={item.isAdaptive && adaptive?.has_quiz}
        quiz={item}
        imgSource={item.topic_image}
        due={item.due_date}
        style={{ marginBottom: 12 }}
        onPress={() => pressQuiz(item, index)}
     />
   );
 }, ["Your dependencies"]);
```

Interesting to read:
[React ‘useMemo’ and ‘useCallback’: When to use them and when not](https://medium.com/credera-engineering/when-should-usememo-and-usecallback-be-used-and-when-not-complete-with-examples-df13cd7a6cf4)

[useMemo - React](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo#skipping-re-rendering-of-components)